# Processing events for scene/view operations in PyQt4

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to figure out what is the 'best' or recommended way performing updates in the QT scene/view framework. I've included a small example illustrating the problem.

The code creates a fullscreen dialog with three buttons. Each button, when clicked, adds a `QGraphicsView` widget with a scene to the dialog and two rectangles are introduced to the scene. The goal is to make the contents of the scene fit in the view widget. Each button tries to perform the fit in different ways:

**naive**: Adds the view/scene, adds the rectangles and calls the fit method. This does not actually end up doing what is needed (i.e., the scene contents are not properly fitted to the view widget).

**processEvents**: In between adding the content and calling the fit method QT `processEvents` is called to ensure everything is updated. Produces the wanted result.

**singleShot**: The content and fit methods are called via QTimer.singleShot after a certain delay (`t1` and `t2`). Works if the delay is "large enough"

So, one method (`processEvents`) works always but I've read that this is kind of a brute force way of achieving the goal and is not recommended. The `singleShot` method sort of works and has the downside of slowing things down (I don't want to wait 200ms for the contents to be fit if it can be done in 50ms).

Is there a way other than these two for getting the desired result?

```py
from PyQt4 import QtGui as QG
from PyQt4 import QtCore as QC
import sys


class MainUI(QG.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainUI, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QG.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        button_layout = QG.QHBoxLayout()
        pb3 = QG.QPushButton('singleShot')
        pb2 = QG.QPushButton('processEvents')
        pb1 = QG.QPushButton('naive')
        button_layout.addWidget(pb1)
        button_layout.addWidget(pb2)
        button_layout.addWidget(pb3)
        layout.addLayout(button_layout)
        pb3.clicked.connect(self.scene_maker_singleshot)
        pb2.clicked.connect(self.scene_maker_processevents)
        pb1.clicked.connect(self.scene_maker_naive)

    def scene_maker_processevents(self):
        self.make_scene()
        QG.QApplication.processEvents()
        self.view.fitInView(self.view.sceneRect())

    def scene_maker_singleshot(self):
        t1 = 100
        t2 = 200
        QC.QTimer.singleShot(t1, self.make_scene)
        QC.QTimer.singleShot(t2, lambda: self.view.fitInView(self.view.sceneRect()))

    def scene_maker_naive(self):
        self.make_scene()
        self.view.fitInView(self.view.sceneRect())


    def make_scene(self):
        layout = self.layout()
        scene = QG.QGraphicsScene()
        view = QG.QGraphicsView()
        view.setScene(scene)
        layout.addWidget(view)
        self.view = view
        scene.addRect(1,1,10,5,brush = QG.QBrush(QG.QColor('red')))
        scene.addRect(11,21,15,5, brush = QG.QBrush(QG.QColor('blue')))

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QG.QApplication(sys.argv)
    screen_size = app.desktop().screenGeometry()
    gui = MainUI()
    gui.show()
    gui.showMaximized()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: The big risk with processEvents() is ending up in a recursive loop of invoking events that invoke events back on each other. You should be able to set the singleShot timeout to 0, which is handled specially, and Qt will invoke the timer when It's finished processing events. This should achieve much the same effect as calling processEvent() but without interfering with the event loop. Not exactly elegant, but I think it should work.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this does not work. That's why I mentioned in the original post that the `singleShot` delays have to be "large enough". With t1=t2=0 the sample code will not fit the rectangles into the view.